# Magento: Home page products disappear if I change a theme

Tags: php, magento

I want to show a specific category of products on home page. So, I have write the following code in content part of home page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Now I can see the products from category 3 on home page. After that I have installed shoe store free theme on my project and activate that theme and suddenly products on home page disappear. Can any one suggest me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this block in home page:

Enter to admin panel -> CMS ->Pages -> Home

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

After this clear cache from System -> cache management

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following file :

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

and paste it to the location :

```
/app/design/frontend/default/yournewtheme/catalog/product/
```

if the inner folders do not exist, please create them and proceed.

I hope this helps.